# Interaction between Dokkan and Hidden Potential

Tags: dragon-ball-z-dokkan-battle

What happens when you Dokkan Awaken a unit with + stats in hidden potential?

Do they get added to the unit after the Dokkan Awaken and are now part of the base stats and hidden potential resets or does the hidden potential stay because you can only do it once or does the hidden potential stats go away and start over?

I'm asking because I do not want to spend my hidden potential orbs on a unit if those stats are taken away, but I also need to know if I should max out my hidden potential now or wait until the unit is fully awoken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you Dokkan awaken a character, any potential routes and nodes that were unlocked before remain unlocked after awakening, and the stat changes remain as well. The stats won't just get tacked onto the dokkan awakened character - they're still bonus stats from the hidden potential.

Comment: Cool so I'm good just to do hidden potential whenever it's available then?

Comment: @FoxMcCloud Absolutely! It'd be pretty silly of the devs to punish you for using hidden potential on your best characters... although with how bad some mobile games are I wouldn't put it past them.

Comment: That's why I needed to ask this question!